# Disable certain ng-template items in p-dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng, disable, ng-template, p-dropdown

I have a `p-dropdown` contructed with `ng-template` (this dropdown presents Languages that can be selected.) I need the languages that have been already selected, to be `disabled`.

This is my dropdown:

```
<p-dropdown 
  [styleClass]="'form-control'" 
  [options]="languages" 
  optionValue="languageID" 
  formControlName="languageID" 
  appendTo="body"
  (onChange)="onLanguageChanged(languagesFormGroup, $event.value)">
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
      <img src="{{item.icon}}"><span>{{item.name}} {{item.languageID}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      <img src="{{item.icon}}"><span>{{item.name}} {{item.languageID}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

I need specific `pTemplate="item"` to be disabled. I tried with angular's `disable`, i tried with `ng-disable`, with `ngIf`, with `[att.disabled]="expression(item)"`, nothing works.

Is there any way to achieve what I need? Please help.

Thanks a lot in advace

Comment: You want to disable selecting particular item?

Comment: Have you tried the `optionDisabled` attribute?  https://primefaces.org/primeng/dropdown

Comment: verify if the object in [options]="languages"  should have a property as disabled: false or true

Comment: I have multiple dropdowns (the user can add or delete multiple selected languages). In the beginning there are two drop-downs with "English" and "Greek" selected. I need these two languages to be disabled in the third (added) dropdown so that the user can't select them again

Answer (score 0):

So I found the correct way to do it. I added a `disabled` property on my `languages` collection. I set `disabled = true` whenever a language is selected and the `ng-template` does the rest by itself. No further code needed.

Thanx everyone for their suggestions!